# Stuck in implementing autocomplete from data from restFul API

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement the autocomplete search bar in the UI.

HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="apexClass" id="autocomplete"/>
</div>
```

I have used the devbridge js:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        type:'POST',
        serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:8989/getSuggestion',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value);
        }
    });
```

Then on the server side I have this Rest service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSuggestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSuggestion(String query) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List<String> strings = stringListHashMap.get("suggestions");
    Iterator itr = strings.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        String x = (String)itr.next();
        if (!x.contains(query))
            itr.remove();
    }
    stringListHashMap.put("suggestions", strings);
    return gson.toJson(stringListHashMap);
}
```

Now the issue is when the page is loaded for the first time I can get the query from the search bar and remove elemnets from the list and show them, but when I delete the query I am not able to retain the values from the list as I have used iterator and removed them.

In devbridge documentation its written that when we use serviceURL it is server side responsibility to filter the results. But I am now stuck.
How can I get this corrected ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the answer, it was from server side. I changed the code as follows:
Keeping the parent data separate and creating a new data set to be passed to the UI. This way the original dataset is always there.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getSuggestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSuggestion(String query) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    List<String> strings = stringListHashMap.get("suggestions");
    Map<String, List<String>> newMapReturn = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> newListToBeAdded = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator itr = strings.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        String x = (String)itr.next();
        if (x.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
            newListToBeAdded.add(x);
    }

    newMapReturn.put("suggestions", newListToBeAdded);
    return gson.toJson(newMapReturn);
}
```